# Enum.GetValues() Return Type

Tags: c#, enums

I have read the documentation that states that "given the type of the enum, the GetValues() method of System.Enum will return an array of the given enum's base type" i.e. int, byte, etc.

However, I have been using the GetValues() method and all I keep getting back is an array of type Enums. Am I missing something?

```cs
public enum Response
{
    Yes = 1,
    No = 2,
    Maybe = 3
} 
          
foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Response)))
{
    var type = value.GetType(); // type is always of type Enum not of the enum base type
}
```

Comment: The ideal syntax would be eg. `Enum.GetValues<Response>()`  but it doesn't exist

Comment: Note that this will work just fine: "foreach (Response value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Response)))"

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You need to cast the result to the actual array type you want

```
(Response[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Response))
```

as GetValues isn't strongly typed

EDIT: just re-read the answer. You need to explicitly cast each enum value to the underlying type, as GetValues returns an array of the actual enum type rather than the base type. Enum.GetUnderlyingType could help with this.

Comment: Also, just to reiterate the point, 'var' is strongly-typed. It won't magically get set to the actual type of the result.

Comment: Regarding your edit : no, it's not necessary to cast each value individually. Casting the array as you wrote in your code works fine

Comment: Am I missing something? The accepted answer returns Response[] while I think the question is looking for int[] (int being the default enum base type). This will do it but perhaps there is a less verbose way. `((IEnumerable<Response>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(Response))).Select(v => (int)v).ToArray()`

Answer (score 47):

If you're using NET 3.5 (i.e. you have LINQ) you can do:

```
var responses = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Response)).Cast<Response>();
```

Answer (score 17):

Personally I've created a separate method in my Utils project, which I include in my other projects. Here's the code I use:

```
public static class EnumUtil
{
    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> GetAllValues<TEnum>() 
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>();
    }   
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
var enumValues = EnumUtil.GetAllValues<Response>();
```

Answer (score 7):

Can you please refer to the documentation you mention. The [documentation on `Enum.GetValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues) does not mention anything like that (quote from that page):

> **Return Value**
>
> Type: System.Array
>
> An Array of the
> values of the constants in enumType.
> The elements of the array are sorted
> by the binary values of the
> enumeration constants.

Comment: Sorry I used the word documentation. I should have said it was an online article I read at this url:
http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson17.aspx

Comment: @Cragly: The result returned from `Enum.GetValues` in that sample will be of the type `Volume[]`. However, note how the for loop is set up: `foreach (byte val in Enum.GetValues(...`. This means that the code will cast each `Volume` value in the array to a `byte`.

Comment: The documentation is now updated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 4):

As [Roger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8446/roger-lipscombe) mentioned in a comment, it would be nice if there was a `Enum.GetValues<MyEnum>()` generic implementation, but there is not.

This problem annoyed the heck out of me, as well, so I created [a library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DiagonacticEnumsExtensions/) in C++/CLI that has generic implementations of all of the static methods on the `Enum` class (as well as a bunch of other generic methods for working with enums).

The library is written in C++/CLI because C# does not support constraining a generic type by System.Enum.  C++/CLI (and the CLR) *do* support constraining by System.Enum and C#/VB.NET has no problem understanding calls to a method that have this constraint.

In the case of your example, you'd use `Enums.GetValues<MyEnumType>()` which will hand you an array of `MyEnumType` without the need to cast.  Though C# and VB.Net do not support defining an enum constraint, they have no problem with consuming a method/class that has such a constraint and intellisense/the compiler handle it perfectly.

Comment: Note that as of C# 7.3, C# *finally* does support `Enum` type constraints: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/104

Comment: Such a generic method, `Enum.GetValues<TEnum>()` was finally introduced in .NET 5 (from 2020).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .NET 5+ you can now use `Enum.GetValues<TEnum>()`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-6.0#system-enum-getvalues-1

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Joel's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18271218/209259) but done a slight different way:

```
public static class Enums<T>
  where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
  static Enums()
  {
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
      throw new ArgumentException("Type T must be an Enum type");  
  }

  public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues()
  {
    var result = ((T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).ToList()

    return result;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<System.Drawing.FontStyle> styles = Enums<System.Drawing.FontStyle>.GetValues();
```