# List of System Colors Property

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I'm looking for a property that returns a list of System Colors. I looked at the `SystemColors` and the `Colors` classes. I couldn't spot a property that would simply return a list of Colors.

I know there are some solutions to get the System Colors, but I rather to use a built in property.

It is odd that the `Fonts` class have the `SystemFontFamilies` property that returns list of `System` `Fonts` and the `Colors` doesn't have such property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enum.GetValues() Return Type].
 The `Colors` enums can be used to give you this array.
 You can then do what you want with the values.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398664/enum-getvalues-return-type)

Comment: What platform are you using winform, wpf, webapp etc?

Comment: @krillgar I don't think OP wants all enum values of `System.Colors`, but the defined colors used by windows by default for borders, titlebars, backgrounds, etc

Comment: @krillgar Colors is a Class and not an Enum in the System.Windows.Media

Comment: @John I'm using wpf

Comment: ok will update answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you looking for and if you have access to System.Drawing (not available in Azure for example).

System.Drawing.SystemColors will tell you the colours the OS uses for drawing parts of the system.

> Each property of the System.Drawing.SystemColors class is a
>   System.Drawing.Color structure that is the color of a Windows display
>   element.

Or you can use the System.Drawing.KnownColor enum a list of colours using [Enum.GetValues() Return Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398664/enum-getvalues-return-type).

As the question has been updated to show you are using then please see this refernace on how to access colours:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, which is from one of my own examples for a Colour Dropdown Control which uses reflection

```
private Dictionary<string, Color> colours = typeof(Colors)
    .GetRuntimeProperties()
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Color = (Color)c.GetValue(null),
        Name = string.Join(" ", splitCapital(c.Name))
    }).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Color);
```

You'll also need the following "using"

```
using System.Reflection;
```