# How can I change enum items using a button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.IMGUI;

public class ChangeShaderRenderingModes : EditorWindow
{
    public enum BlendMode
    {
        Opaque,
        Cutout,
        Fade,
        Transparent
    }

    static Material material;
    static Material objectMat;
    static int modeIndex = 0;

    [MenuItem("Tools/Change Rendering Modes")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<ChangeShaderRenderingModes>("ChangeRenderingModes");
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(50,50,50,50), "Switch Mode"))
        {
            var objects = Selection.objects;

            Shader shader = Shader.Find("Standard");
            material = new Material(shader);

            if (modeIndex == 4)
                modeIndex = 0;

            ChangeRenderMode(material, BlendMode.Opaque);

            GameObject go = GameObject.Find("test");

            objectMat = go.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial;
            objectMat = material;
            go.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = material;
        }
    }

    public static void ChangeRenderMode(Material standardShaderMaterial, BlendMode blendMode)
    {
        switch (blendMode)
        {
            case BlendMode.Opaque:
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.One);
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.Zero);
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_ZWrite", 1);
                standardShaderMaterial.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.DisableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.renderQueue = -1;
                break;
            case BlendMode.Cutout:
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.One);
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.Zero);
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_ZWrite", 1);
                standardShaderMaterial.EnableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.DisableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.renderQueue = 2450;
                break;
            case BlendMode.Fade:
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
                standardShaderMaterial.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.renderQueue = 3000;
                break;
            case BlendMode.Transparent:
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.One);
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
                standardShaderMaterial.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
                standardShaderMaterial.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.DisableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.EnableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
                standardShaderMaterial.renderQueue = 3000;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make that each time I click the button it will change to the next mode. Opaque, Cutout, Fade, Transparent

And after Transparent back to the first one Opaque

The problem is that the method ChangeRenderMode get one specific mode.
I want when clicking the button once ChangeRenderMode will get Opaque then next click it will get Cutout then Fade and Transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum`s start with default value of 0, increasing 1 per item, so

```
public enum BlendMode
{
    Opaque,   // = 0
    Cutout,   // = 1
    Fade,     // = 2
    Transparent  // = 3
}
```

So you can parse it into `int` calculate the next value and then parse it again to `BlendMode`:

In your `OnGUI` function, replace

```
if (modeIndex == 4)
    modeIndex = 0;
ChangeRenderMode(material, BlendMode.Opaque);
```

with

```
var values = (BlendMode[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(BlendMode))
modeIndex = (BlendMode)((modeIndex+1) % values.Length);
ChangeRenderMode(material, blendMode);
```

Comment: Tried the modeIndex is 0 all the time after clicking the button.

Comment: to be more flexible and not rely on hardcoded indexes you could use [`var values = (BlendMode[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(BlendMode))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398664/enum-getvalues-return-type) to get all values and use modulo like `modeIndex = (modeIndex+1) % values.Length;`. I think that reads easy and requires two lines without if-else

Comment: It seems to be working now but there is another problem. When I click the button I see on my character the changes of each mode. But when I click on the inspector to expand the shader it's changing back automatic the mode to Opaque. When I click the button and it's changing mode it's making the shade in the inspector unexpended, So I click on the arrow to see what mode it is now and it's changing it back to Opaque. Is there anything to do about that ?

Comment: it has nothing to do with this part of the code, may be somewhere else you are changing it, it resets the enum value.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani in your code example you now confused `modeIndex` with `blendMode` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a `Dictionary` key be current state value be next state.

```
Dictionary<BlendMode, BlendMode> dict = new Dictionary<BlendMode, BlendMode>();
dict.Add(BlendMode.Opaque, BlendMode.Cutout);
dict.Add(BlendMode.Cutout, BlendMode.Fade);
dict.Add(BlendMode.Fade, BlendMode.Transparent);
dict.Add(BlendMode.Transparent, BlendMode.Opaque);
```

and declare a value in the class to store `BlendMode` state.

```
BlendMode currentMode = BlendMode.Cutout;
```

Then you can use this currentMode (key) to get the next Mode.

```
currentMode = dict[currentMode];
```

Full code will be like

```
public class ChangeShaderRenderingModes : EditorWindow
{
    //store mode
    static BlendMode currentMode = BlendMode.Opaque;

    static Dictionary<BlendMode, BlendMode> dict = new Dictionary<BlendMode, BlendMode>();


    public void Awake()
    {
        dict.Add(BlendMode.Opaque, BlendMode.Cutout);
        dict.Add(BlendMode.Cutout, BlendMode.Fade);
        dict.Add(BlendMode.Fade, BlendMode.Transparent);
        dict.Add(BlendMode.Transparent, BlendMode.Opaque);
    }


    public enum BlendMode
    {
        Opaque,
        Cutout,
        Fade,
        Transparent
    }

    static Material material;
    static Material objectMat;
    static int modeIndex = 0;

    [MenuItem("Tools/Change Rendering Modes")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<ChangeShaderRenderingModes>("ChangeRenderingModes");
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(50,50,50,50), "Switch Mode"))
        {
            var objects = Selection.objects;

            Shader shader = Shader.Find("Standard");
            material = new Material(shader);

            if (modeIndex == 4)
                modeIndex = 0;

            // take out the parameter
            ChangeRenderMode(material);

            GameObject go = GameObject.Find("test");

            objectMat = go.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial;
            objectMat = material;
            go.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = material;
        }
    }

    public static void ChangeRenderMode(Material standardShaderMaterial)
    {
        switch (blendMode)
        {
            ....
        }
        // set next mode
        currentMode = dict[currentMode];
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

This solution can be flexible to determine what the next Mode is.

Comment: While this...functions, you introduce a point of code failure if the enum ever gets updated.