# c# running stuck in foreach block

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's very incredible that my code stopped running in a foreach block:

```
        Debug.Log("Start");
        GameSystem.players.ForEach(player => {
            Debug.Log(player.name);
            Debug.Log(player.developCard_GetThisTurn.Count);
            foreach (DevelopCardType type in player.developCard_GetThisTurn.Keys)
            {
                Debug.Log(type);
                player.developCard_GetThisTurn[type] = 0;
                Debug.Log("=0"); // stuck at here
            }
            Debug.Log("next");
        });
        Debug.Log("End?");
```

The Definition and Initialization of player and developCard_GetThisTurn is as fllowing:

```
public class GamePlayer
{
    public Dictionary<DevelopCardType, int> developCard_GetThisTurn;
    public void Setup()
    {
        developCard_GetThisTurn = new Dictionary<DevelopCardType, int>();
        foreach (DevelopCardType developCardType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DevelopCardType)))
        {
            developCard_GetThisTurn[developCardType] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

These code is Running in Unity, calling stack is as follow:

```
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Interpreter/<>c:<Code601>b__20_0 (GamePlayer) (at Assets/Scripts/SceneGame/Game/Interpreter.cs:560)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1<GamePlayer>:ForEach (System.Action`1<GamePlayer>)
Interpreter:Code601 (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int>) (at Assets/Scripts/SceneGame/Game/Interpreter.cs:553)
Interpreter:Excute (ActionContent) (at Assets/Scripts/SceneGame/Game/Interpreter.cs:86)
Interpreter:HandleActionMessageRecive (ActionContent) (at Assets/Scripts/SceneGame/Game/Interpreter.cs:17)
MessageSystem:LoadMessageAndExcute (GameMessage) (at Assets/Scripts/GameConnection.cs:228)
MessageSystem/<OfflineReciveMessage>d__10:MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/GameConnection.cs:202)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:ExecuteTasks ()
```

I'm confused with this problem, because I can't find any reason for it's stopping.Is there any tip? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to cast your:

`Enum.GetValues(typeof(DevelopCardType)`

To:

`(DevelopCardType [])Enum.GetValues(typeof(DevelopCardType)`

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398664/enum-getvalues-return-type)

So the code would be:

```
foreach (DevelopCardType developCardType in (DevelopCardType [])Enum.GetValues(typeof(DevelopCardType)))
{
    developCard_GetThisTurn[developCardType] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find it's another problem: code throw a error but handled by an unknown catch, i catch it now, it says "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.". I will change the question later. Thanks again.

Comment: Makes sense. That is because you are changing the `developCard_GetThisTurn` dictionary in the same `foreach` loop. You should not loop through a data structure and change that data structure while looping, that breaks as the error very clearly says.